# no difference between Fast DDS Server Listener and simple listener

Tags: dds

**How to make the listener connected to DDS server respond and the listener not connecterd to DDS server not respond**

ROS Humble Fast DDs Tutorial says

the listener not connected to DDS server should not be receiving any messages

[image]

however, it does

below is my .bashrc,

[image]

below is starting DDS talker

> eungoffice@seungoffice-ThinkPad-L15-Gen-1:~$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp
> talker --ros-args --remap __node:=talker_discovery_server [INFO]
> [1702254437.388329258] [talker_discovery_server]: Publishing: 'Hello
> World: 1' [INFO] [1702254438.388635036] [talker_discovery_server]:
> Publishing: 'Hello World: 2' [INFO] [1702254439.388293143]
> [talker_discovery_server]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 3'

below is DDS Listener, and is receiving messages well

> seungoffice@seungoffice-ThinkPad-L15-Gen-1:~$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp
> listener --ros-args --remap __node:=listener_discovery_server [INFO]
> [1702254473.388553972] [listener_discovery_server]: I heard: [Hello
> World: 37] [INFO] [1702254474.388571777] [listener_discovery_server]:
> I heard: [Hello World: 38] [INFO] [1702254475.388951752]
> [listener_discovery_server]: I heard: [Hello World: 39]

below is not a DDS Listener, but just an simple listener

should be not answering from talker
but it is getting message
**how to stop Simple Listener from getting message from DDS Talker**

> seungoffice@seungoffice-ThinkPad-L15-Gen-1:~$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp
> listener --ros-args --remap __node:=simple_listener [INFO]
> [1702254444.388796486] [simple_listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 8]
> [INFO] [1702254445.389075789] [simple_listener]: I heard: [Hello
> World: 9] [INFO] [1702254446.388995321] [simple_listener]: I heard:
> [Hello World: 10] [INFO] [1702254447.388870217] [simple_listener]: I
> heard: [Hello World: 11] [INFO] [1702254448.388776405]
> [simple_listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 12]

[image]
humble tutorial page
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Discovery-Server/Discovery-Server.html

Comment: Copy and paste text into the question instead of using screenshots of text

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.